# Dispatching reducers with different action types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am new to typescript and redux. I am trying to migrate my project to redux. It's already in typescript, it was just using react context api. This is simple description of my code:

**exerciseActions.ts**

```
export function getExercises() {
   return async (dispatch: Dispatch<IExerciseAction>) => {
       //if fetch ok dispatch exercises loaded to ExercisesReducer
       // if not ok dispatch stop loading to ExercisesReducer 
       // and dispatch notification action to NotificationReducer
   }
}
```

**notificationActions.ts**

```
export function openNotification(msg: string, msgType: MsgType //error, into, etc.) {
   // dispatch action to Notification reducer -> displaying f.e. error message in snackbar
}
```

**exerciseReducer.ts**

```
// handle IExerciseAction -> update data, loading state...
```

**notificationReducer.ts**

```
// handle INotificationAction -> display notification to user
```

I have a problem when trying to dispatch openNotification function to notificationActions.ts from function getExercises in exerciseActions.ts. I tried putting IExerciseAction | in INotificationAction in getExercises(), and searched if someone had a similar problem, without any help. I am happy to hear any advice.

Comment: What is the problem? If it's a type problem you may have to import [ThunkDispatch](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.d.ts#L20) or [ThunkAction](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.d.ts#L50) instead of the redux types.

Comment: @HMR If I have Dispatch<IExerciseAction | INotificationAction> then there is an error when caling dispatch(openNotification(......));


TS2345: Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch<INotificationAction>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IExerciseAction | INotificationAction'.   Type '(dispatch: Dispatch<INotificationAction>) => void' is missing the following properties from type 'INotificationAction': message, type

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion from @HMR to use ThunkDispatch Helped. I changed code to:

```
export function getExercises() {
    return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<ExercisesState, void, IExerciseAction | INotificationAction>) => {
        //...
   }
}
```